# Copy range to new worksheet fails

Tags: vba, excel

VBA newbie having trouble copying a sheet into another with offset.

Copying the entire sheet works but I can't get copy with offset to function the same way.

What am I missing?

```
source.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'works
source.Range("A12").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to paste a range on a sheet object, but you need to specify the initial range (top left cell) where you want to paste in that sheet! ;)

```
source.Range("A12").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")
```

You could also use "range-transfer" which is far more efficient than copy :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Value = source.Range("A12").Value
```

And here is how to create a new sheet and paste from the old one :

```
Sub test_frostbite()
Dim wB As Workbook, _
    WsNEW As Worksheet, _
    Source As Worksheet

Set wB = ActiveWorkbook
Set Source = wB.Sheets("SheetName")
Set WsNEW = wB.Sheets.Add

Source.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=WsNEW.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: This did not create a new sheet (like the copy without range)

Comment: Nope, because this is a different issue and line in code, let me edit and add that! ;) @frostbite : see the edit! ;)

Comment: worked like a charm. Please can you explain the need to create the sheet explicitly for range copy.

Comment: It is just that you canNOT implicitly create a sheet while you copy a range, you can if you copy the sheet as itself and then you do your operations on this one. Or you create a new sheet and then paste the data!